# How can I add and synchronize a scrollbar at the top and bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create top and bottom scrollbars on a table in angular1 using a directive.  Although it creates the scroll bars the top scrollbar thumb doesn't appear even if there is an overflow in the table.  Below is the code.  Where exactly am I going wrong here?

```
angular.module('app.doubleHorizontalScrollDirective', []).directive('doubleHorizontalScroll', [
```

'$interval',
  function($interval){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',

```
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {

    // ng-repeat delays the actual width of the element.
    // this listens for the change and updates the scroll bar
    function widthListener() {
      if (anchor.width() !== lastWidth)
        updateScroll();
    }

    function updateScroll() {
      // for whatever reason this gradually takes away 1 pixel when it sets the width.
      $div2.width(anchor.width());

      // make the scroll bars the same width
      $div1.width($div2.width());

      // sync the real scrollbar with the virtual one.
      $wrapper1.scroll(function(){
        $wrapper2.scrollLeft($wrapper1.scrollLeft());
      });

      // sync the virtual scrollbar with the real one.
      $wrapper2.scroll(function(){
        $wrapper1.scrollLeft($wrapper2.scrollLeft());
      });
    }

    let anchor = element.find('[data-anchor]'),
      lastWidth = anchor.width(),
      listener;

    // so that when you go to a new link it stops listening
    element.on('remove', function() {
      listener.cancel();
    });

    // creates the top virtual scrollbar
    element.wrapInner("<div class='div2' />");
    element.wrapInner("<div class='wrapper2' />");

    // contains the element with a real scrollbar
    element.prepend("<div class='wrapper1'><div class='div1'></div></div>");

    let $wrapper1 = element.find('.wrapper1'),
      $div1 = element.find('.div1'),
      $wrapper2 = element.find('.wrapper2'),
      $div2 = element.find('.div2');

    // force our virtual scrollbar to work the way we want.
    $wrapper1.css({
      width: "100%",
      border: "none 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
      overflowX: "scroll",
      overflowY: "hidden",
      height: "20px",
    });

    $div1.css({
      height: "20px",
    });

    $wrapper2.css({
      width: "100%",
      overflowX: "scroll",
    });

    listener = $interval(function() {
      widthListener();
    }, 1000);

    updateScroll();
  }
```

};
}]);

> HTML:

```
 <div id="scroll-container"
       double-horizontal-scroll>
    <div data-anchor>
      <div class="video-analysis__default_table__header">
          <table>
              <tr>
                <th class="video-analysis__default_table__header--index fixed-left-index "><!--<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>--></th>
                  <th class="video-analysis__default_table__header--checkbox fixed-left-checkbox"><div class="relative"></div></th>
                  <th class="video-analysis__default_table__header--star fixed-left-star" ng-click="sortClips('starred')">
                    <div class="relative">
                      <i ng-show="isSortType('starred') && sortDirection == 1" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                      <i ng-show="isSortType('starred') && sortDirection == -1" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </div>
                  </th>

                  <th ng-repeat="header in currentHeaders"
                      ng-class="'video-analysis__default_table__header--' + header.class"
                      ng-click="sortClips(header.sorting_column)"
                  >
                    <span ng-bind="header.header_title"></span>
                    <i ng-show="isSortType(header.sorting_column) && sortDirection == 1" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                    <i ng-show="isSortType(header.sorting_column) && sortDirection == -1" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  </th>

                <th ng-show="emptySpaceExists()"
                    ng-style="{'width' : remainingWidth + 'px'}">
                </th>

                  <th class="video-analysis__default_table__header--plus fixed-right"
                      ng-click="show_table_data = !show_table_data; $event.stopPropagation();">
                    <span class="fa fa-cog fa-2x" ng-show="show_table_data"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-2x" ng-hide="show_table_data"></span>
                  </th>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>

      <div class="video-analysis__default_table__item" ng-hide="!show_table_data">
          <div class="panel video-analysis__default_table__item__panel"
               ng-repeat="item in clips track by $index"
               ng-init="is_collapsed = true;"
               ng-style="{'margin-bottom' : !is_collapsed ? '150px' : '0px'}"
          >
              <div class="panel-body video-analysis__default_table__item__panel__body">
                  <table>
                    <tbody id="clip_data_table">
                      <tr class="clickable" ng-click="playClip(item)" ng-mouseenter="color = 'clip-hover'" ng-mouseleave="color = ''">
                          <td class="video-analysis__default_table__item__panel__body--index fixed-left-index"
                          >
                              <div class="relative" ng-bind="$index + 1"  ng-class="color"></div>
                          </td>

                          <td class="video-analysis__default_table__item__panel__body--checkbox fixed-left-checkbox">
                            <div class="relative" ng-class="color">
                              <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleClipCollection(item); $event.stopPropagation();" ng-checked="is_InClipCollection(item)">
                            </div>
                          </td>

                          <td class="video-analysis__default_table__item__panel__body--star fixed-left-star">
                            <div class="relative" ng-class="color">
                                  <i class="fa fa-favorite"
                                     ng-click="toggleStarredClip(item); $event.stopPropagation();"
                                     ng-class="{active: isStarredClip(item)}"
                                  >

                                  </i>
                            </div>
                          </td>

                          <td ng-repeat="column in currentHeaders"
                              ng-class="'video-analysis__default_table__item__panel__body--' + column.class +' '+color"
                          >
                            <span ng-bind="getClipDatum(column.sorting_column, item)"></span>
                          </td>

                          <td ng-show="emptySpaceExists()"
                              ng-style="{'width' : remainingWidth + 'px'}">
                          </td>

                          <td class="video-analysis__default_table__item__panel__body--plus fixed-right"
                              ng-click="is_collapsed = !is_collapsed; $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <div class="relative" ng-class="color">
                              <span class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" ng-show="is_collapsed"></span>
                              <span class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-2x" ng-hide="is_collapsed"></span>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>

              <div class="panel-footer video-analysis__default_table__item__panel__footer"
                   ng-hide="is_collapsed">

                      <div class="col-md-5 padding-0">
                          <table>
                              <tr class="teams-row">
                                  <th class="team-name-column" ng-bind="item.game.awayteam.abbrev"></th>
                                  <th class="positions-column"></th>
                                  <th class="team-name-column" ng-bind="item.game.hometeam.abbrev"></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr ng-show="item.lineup.length === 0"
                                  ng-repeat="position in positions"
                              >
                                  <td class="player-name-column text-center"><span ng-if="$index == 3">Data Not Available</span></td>
                                  <td class="positions-column border-left-right"><span ng-bind="position"></span></td>
                                  <td class="player-name-column text-center"><span ng-if="$index == 3">Data Not Available</span></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr ng-show="item.lineup.length !== 0"
                                  ng-repeat="(position_key, position) in item.lineup"
                              >
                                  <td class="player-name-column text-left">
                                      <span class="player-name"
                                              ng-bind="'#'+position.away.iplayerjerseynumber+' '
                                          +position.away.abbrev_name">
                                      </span>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="positions-column border-left-right">
                                      <span ng-bind="position_key"></span>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="player-name-column text-left">
                                      <span class="player-name"
                                          ng-bind="'#'+position.home.iplayerjerseynumber+' '
                                          +position.home.abbrev_name">
                                      </span>
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-5 padding-0">

                              <div class="video-analysis-col-notes">
                                  <div class="notes-title">
                                      <span>notes: </span>
                                      <button class="edit-button"
                                              ng-click="toggleForm(notesEform)">
                                          <span ng-show="notesEform.$visible">
                                              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>save
                                          </span>
                                          <span ng-show="!notesEform.$visible">
                                              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>edit
                                          </span>
                                      </button>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="notes-content"
                                       editable-textarea="item.detailed_notes"
                                       buttons="no"
                                       blur="submit"
                                       onaftersave="saveXeditable(item.iclipid, item);"
                                       e-form="notesEform"
                                       ng-bind="item.detailed_notes"
                                  >
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 padding-0">
                          <div class="dropdown-actions">
                              <div class="padding-2px">
                              <button class="action-button" ng-click="playClip(item)">play</button>
                              <button class="action-button" ng-click="editClip(item)">edit clip</button>
                              <!--<button class="action-button">add to playlist</button>-->
                              <!--<button class="action-button">share</button>-->
                              <button class="action-button" ng-click="syndicateClip(item)">syndicate</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
              </div>

          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> CSS

```
 #scroll-container {
  margin-left: 106px;
  margin-right: 40px;
```

}